# Adding a setTimeout method makes the jQuery hover method ignore the function inside the setTimeout method

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says and if I remove the setTimeout method it works but I need a delay before the function fires.

```
$( ".pa-wrap" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).find( ".pa-ano-wrap" ).css({
            "display": "block", 
            "opacity": 0

        }).animate({
            "opacity": 0.8

        }, 200);
    }, function() {
        $( this ).find( ".pa-ano-wrap" ).animate({
            "opacity": 0

        }, 200);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $( this ).find( ".pa-ano" ).css({
                "height": "24px",
                "top": "-33px"
            });
        }, 201);
    }
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by ignore? Does it not run now?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't run the function.

Comment: Assign $(this) to something before the timeout, as your context and therefore its meaning has changed. Having said that, the placement of your setTimeout seems odd

Comment: @aw04 Can you explain how it is odd? I'm not great with JS yet.

Comment: @Pheta Sure. Do what Adam below says, if you look at the animate documentation... you can specify a callback that will fire when the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `this` refers to the current context which has changed by `setTimeout`, thus you need to bind it to the one you want:

```
setTimeout(function() {
// ...
}.bind(this), 201);
```

Also I would recommend from both performance and readility reasons to cache the element:

```
var paWrap = $('.pa-wrap');
paWrap.hover(function() {
    paWrap.find('.pa-ano-wrap').css({
// and so on
});
```

It also helps with all this `this` confusion since you always know what `this` refers to.

Comment: Better yet to not yet `setTimeout` at all and make that function a callback after the animation finishes.

Comment: @Pheta I've added extra recommendation; also if the question is answered for you, please mark it as such.

Comment: @peter Thank you for the help. I will mark it as soon as it lets me and I understand the recommendation but using the variable will refer the CSS edit to all of the elements with that class which was the whole point in using the "this" selector - causing the problem in the first place. Is there a way to give you rep on this site?

Comment: @Pheta Just replace that line with 'var paWrap = $(this);' At that point, $(this) means what you want it to.

Comment: @aw04 Thanks for making his suggestion useful in my scenario but would it not make more sense to call the variable "this" instead, making it a variable I could use in other parts of the code?

Comment: `this` is reserved symbol, so you cannot assign to it, only read from it. Also the caching happens on the selector, so all elements with that class will be still there, not just one.